# Getting Contacts from user's phone

Tags: android, firebase, contacts, android-contacts, data-retrieval

I am developing a simple messenger app using firebase(for backend). I wish to compare the contact phonenumbers of the user to the contact phone numbers stored in my database,so that user can view a refined list of contacts. I have looked up in google but I could not find a way to get the numbers stored in a separate variable. I tried the below code from another post in stack overflow but i am getting an error at getactivity saying "cannot resolve method"

```
        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        int phoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                        String phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        switch (phoneType) {
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                Log.e(name + "(mobile number)", phoneNumber);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                Log.e(name + "(home number)", phoneNumber);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                Log.e(name + "(work number)", phoneNumber);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                Log.e(name + "(other number)", phoneNumber);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }


        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably if you are using that code inside Activity than i think getActivity() is not required ,you can directly call getContentResolver() but if still doesn't work than try this to get contacts and other details . I am copying code from one of my project so hope you will understand that

```
 ArrayList<DeviceContacts> contactsList = new ArrayList<DeviceContacts>();
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

            // read id
            String id = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            /** read names **/
            displayName = null;
            displayName = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            /** read image uri's **/
            imageuri = null;
            imageuri = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

            /** Phone Numbers **/
            Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
            number = null;
            typeStr = null;
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                number = pCur
                        .getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                typeStr = pCur
                        .getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                Log.i("ContactsList", "Contact number :" + number);
                Log.i("ContactsList", "Number type :" + typeStr);

            }
            pCur.close();
            /** EMAIL **/
            Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

            email = null;

            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                email = emailCur
                        .getString(emailCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

            }

            DeviceContacts dContacts = new DeviceContacts(); // simple model class
            dContacts.setDisplayName(displayName);
            dContacts.setmNumber(number);
            dContacts.setEmail(email);
            dContacts.setImageUri(imageuri);
            contactsList.add(dContacts); 

            emailCur.close();

        }
    }
    cur.close();
```

hope this can help

Comment: Thank you Mukesh for replying... I will try out the code and I will give you my feedback :)

Comment: Go ahead and have success :)